# Mocking a constructor inside a static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, processbuilder

Following is the code I am trying to unit test

```
public final class ClassToBeTested {
    public static void function(String arg) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(arg);
        //Using pb here
    }
}
```

I want to mock the constructor invocation (new File(arg)), here
I tried using Power Mock :

```
@PrepareForTest({ClassToBeTested.class})
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void functionTest() throws Exception {
        String str = "abc";
        ProcessBuilder mockProcessBuilder = PowerMock.createMock(ProcessBuilder.class);

        PowerMock.expectNew(ProcessBuilder.class, str).andReturn(mockProcessBuilder);

        PowerMock.replay(mockProcessBuilder, ProcessBuilder.class);

        ClassToBeTested.function(abc);

    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. As new ProcessBuilder(arg) is not returning the mocked object.

Comment: Even if it worked, it would be useless in my view - a constructor call can *never* return `null`, so why would you want to test a situation when it did? Why are you trying to mock `File` anyway?

Comment: (And following https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor, you'd normally use `replay(fileMock, File.class)`.)

Comment: Actually the use of File and null is just an example here

Comment: Well how about you give an example which *doesn't* involve `null`, so that you can call `replay` appropriately? (As per the docs I linked to.)

Comment: Added the exact code I want to test

Comment: Do you also have `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

Comment: Eclipse showed an error, when I tried to add (@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)), link: (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/LCwMDVjiumI) helped to fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` helped to resolve the issue.

Also using `PowerMock.replayAll()`.